# GridView из файла

Tags: php, yii2, gridview

Такая проблема есть тестовый проект на yii2. И нужно из 2 xml файлов собрать массив и вывести в gridView, сам массив собрать не особо сложно проблема в том, что надо что бы gridView можно было сортировать и фильтровать, но как это сделать если данные из файла ??

Файлы выглядят так:

```
<categories>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Dell</name>
    </item>
    ...
</categories>

<products>
    <item>
        <id>1</id>
        <categoryId>1</categoryId>
        <price>100</price>
        <hidden>1</hidden>
    </item>
    ...
</products>
```

Comment: У `ArrayDataProvider` совсем сложно с сортировкой и фильтрацией, поэтому надо бы использовать `ActiveDataProvider`. Но для этого потребуется сохранять данные в БД, что не очень удобно, хотя и не сложно.

Comment: @fedornabilkin Ну у меня была задача вывести именно из файла без сохранения в базу, если бы можно было сохранять в базу у меня бы проблем не было.